# How to create PAGE using Onenote MS Graph API with Python

Tags: python, onenote-api

Have a good day.

Hope you could help me to solve this problem when I tried to create new page in Onenote using Python.

My code is

```
    R_HEADERS_NOTE = {
        'Host': 'graph.microsoft.com',
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + ['access_token'],
        'Content-type': 'text/html' 
    }
    
    title = "Some demo page title"
    text = "Demo for body"
    
    html = "<html><head><title>" + title + "</title></head>"
    html += "<body><p>" + text + "</p></body></html>"
    
    create_page = requests.request('POST',base_url + 'me/sections/{id}/pages', \
        headers=R_HEADERS_NOTE, data=html)
```

Even I tried with json formatted

```
    create_page = requests.request('POST',base_url + 'me/sections/{id}, \
        headers=R_HEADERS_NOTE, data=json.dumps(html))
```

The response was still error code **400**

> b'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "BadRequest",\r\n    "message":
> **"Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header."**,\r\n
> "innerError": {\r\n      "date": "2021-02-17T06:52:50",\r\n
> "request-id": "708cbd3b-5b3c-489a-a69d-29903b40d5e0",\r\n
> "client-request-id": "708cbd3b-5b3c-489a-a69d-29903b40d5e0"\r\n
> }\r\n  }\r\n}'

I also try to searching to create html using lxml module but it not worked as well.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It my mistake to use incorrect API link

Should be

```
URL_PAGE
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{id}/pages'
```

Instead of

```
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sections/{id}/pages'
```